# MegaRAID nagios monitoring

Tags: python, python-3.x, plugins, monitoring, nagios

I have been beating my head against the wall, trying to figure out what is wrong with the following nagios plugin I wrote. When I run the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import paramiko
import os.path
import sys
OK = 0
WARNING = 1
CRITICAL = 2
DEPENDENT = 3
UNKNOWN = 4
active = str("Active")
online = str("Online")
optimal = str("Optimal")
k = str("OK")
degrade = str("Degraded")
fail = str("Failed")
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(
        hostname='<hostname>',
        username='<service account>', 
        key_filename=os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), ".ssh", "id_rsa.pub")
        )
stdin,stdout,stderr = client.exec_command("sudo /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -ShowSummary -a0")
check = str(stdout.read().decode('ascii'))
client.close()
OK_STR = str("RAID is OK!")
WARN_STR = str("Warning! Something is wrong with the RAID!")
CRIT_STR = str("CRITICAL! THE RAID IS BROKEN")
UNK_STR = str("Uh oh! Something ain't right?")
print(check)
if (degrade) in (check):
    print(WARN_STR) and sys.exit(WARNING)
elif (fail) in (check):
    print(CRIT_STR) and sys.exit(CRITICAL)
elif str('Exit Code: 0x00') in (check):
    print(OK_STR) and sys.exit(OK) 
else:
    sys.exit(UNKNOWN) and print(UNK_STR)
```

I recieve the output that I expect running it from CLI. If I change my logic on the if statement, the exit code changes and I have verified using 'echo $?'.

However, in my LibreNMS front end, I receive  no stdout message and an exit code of 1, which is not how my code outputs in the terminal. If anybody can find something wrong with my code, I really need the help.

Comment: LibreNMS is not Nagios. Regardless, for the testing to make sense you have to ensure that you are running the CLI command as Nagios/whatever would, so su to that user first.

Comment: I am aware, however LibreNMS has integration for Nagios plugins and the plugins are referred to as such.

Comment: As I said, if you're getting exit code 1 that's because that is what the script is returning. The only question is why, and to figure that out you need to run it as close to how your monitoring application would run it as possible. Run the exact check command as the user running your application, check the exit code and output.

Comment: For example, I see your script is running `sudo /opt/MegaRAID/MegaCli/MegaCli64 -ShowSummary -a0` -- if that's not a command that the application user is allowed to run as root, that would probably result in exit 1.